# Permutations Questions - How many ways to order books with constraint?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question:

> There are 50 books.  Dan tries to order them. His only constraint is $5$
>   books by Dan Brown that need to be next to each other. How many
>   possible orders for the $50$ books are there that satisfy this
>   constraint?

Based on my intuition, this is a permutations question, and the answer is $46! \cdot 5!$.

First, we need to order all the books (include a place for $5$ books by Dan Brown. Second, we need to order the books by Dan Brown. Is my intuition correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!